# Sender and Receiver application's output for EventHub functions

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I run the sender class application for event hub functions in java.

Below is the output:

```
    [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505]: Emitting a single connection.
    [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net] entityPath[es-product-response]: Setting next AMQP channel.
    [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net] entityPath[es-product-response]: Next AMQP channel received, updating 0 current subscribers
    [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505]: Creating and starting connection to eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net:5671
    [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], message[Starting reactor.]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionInit hostname[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net], connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], amqpHostname[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ReactorHandler - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505] reactor.onReactorInit
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionLocalOpen hostname[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net], connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionBound hostname[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net], connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionRemoteOpen hostname[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net], connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], remoteContainer[9a601b06673244199cada1f79756354e_G5]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net] entityPath[es-product-response]: Channel is now active.
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - Setting CBS channel.
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - Emitting new response channel. connectionId: MF_d786b4_1613550678505. entityPath: $cbs. linkName: cbs.
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RequestResponseChannel - namespace[MF_d786b4_1613550678505] entityPath[$cbs]: Setting next AMQP channel.
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RequestResponseChannel - namespace[MF_d786b4_1613550678505] entityPath[$cbs]: Next AMQP channel received, updating 0 current subscribers
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SessionHandler - onSessionRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], entityName[es-product-response], sessionIncCapacity[0], sessionOutgoingWindow[2147483647]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler - onLinkLocalOpen connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], entityPath[$cbs], linkName[cbs:receiver], localSource[Source{address='$cbs', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter=null, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SessionHandler - onSessionRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], entityName[cbs-session], sessionIncCapacity[0], sessionOutgoingWindow[2147483647]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SendLinkHandler - onLinkRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], entityPath[$cbs], linkName[cbs:sender], remoteTarget[Target{address='$cbs', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, capabilities=null}]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RequestResponseChannel - namespace[MF_d786b4_1613550678505] entityPath[$cbs]: Channel is now active.
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ReceiveLinkHandler - onLinkRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], entityPath[$cbs], linkName[cbs:receiver], remoteSource[Source{address='$cbs', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter=null, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RequestResponseChannel - namespace[MF_d786b4_1613550678505] entityPath[$cbs]: Channel is now active.
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ActiveClientTokenManager - Scheduling refresh token task. scopes[amqp://eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net/es-product-response]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorSession - Creating a new sender link with linkName es-product-response
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SendLinkHandler - onLinkRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], entityPath[es-product-response], linkName[es-product-response], remoteTarget[Target{address='es-product-response', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, capabilities=null}]
    [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - Upstream connection publisher was completed. Terminating processor.
    [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net] entityPath[es-product-response]: AMQP channel processor completed. Notifying 0 subscribers.
    [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubReactorAmqpConnection - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505]: Disposing of connection.
    [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], errorCondition[n/a]: Disposing of ReactorConnection.
    [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505]: Removing session 'es-product-response'
    [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorSession - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], sessionId[es-product-response], errorCondition[n/a]: Disposing of session.
    [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505]: Removing session 'cbs-session'
    [main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorSession - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], sessionId[cbs-session], errorCondition[n/a]: Disposing of session.
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], message[Processing all pending tasks and closing old reactor.]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SendLinkHandler - onLinkLocalClose connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], linkName[es-product-response], errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.ConnectionHandler - onConnectionLocalClose hostname[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net], connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], errorCondition[null], errorDescription[null]
    [reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor - connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], message[Stopping the reactor because thread was interrupted or the reactor has no more events to process.]
[main] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.AmqpExceptionHandler - Shutdown received: ReactorExecutor.close() was called., isTransient[false], initiatedByClient[true]
    [main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - namespace[eqix-es-uat2-eventhub.servicebus.windows.net] entityPath[es-product-response]: Channel is disposed.
```

**What does this mean?** Is it successfully running or are there some failures?

It is not stopping for long. Please guide, as I need to understand what it is.

Answer (score 1):

From your logs, it is successfully able to create, authorize, and open a send link (`onLinkRemoteOpen`) to your Event Hub, `es-product-response`. The subsequent log says that someone is disposing of the `EventHubConnectionProcessor` which owns the AMQP sessions and links.

```
[reactor-executor-1] INFO com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SendLinkHandler - onLinkRemoteOpen connectionId[MF_d786b4_1613550678505], entityPath[es-product-response], linkName[es-product-response], remoteTarget[Target{address='es-product-response', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, capabilities=null}]
[main] INFO com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubConnectionProcessor - Upstream connection publisher was completed. Terminating processor.
```

Do you have a code snippet of your Azure Function?